# First class runtime environment vs second runtime environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I read in the book titled [Modern Full-Stack Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484257375) that:

> Node is a **first-class runtime environment**, meaning that you can do such things as
> interacting with the local file system, access relational databases, call remote systems, and much more. In the past, you’d have to use a “proper” runtime, such as Java or .Net to do all this; JavaScript wasn’t a player in that space. With Node, this is no longer true. It can compete not only on performance but also in terms of what capabilities it provides to developers. If you can think of it, chances are you can do it with Node, and that wasn’t always the case with JavaScript.

I wonder what a first-class runtime environment is? Is there a second class runtime environment? I have googled but found nothing except this article: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/First_class_environments, and it seems to have no bearing on what the above quote reads.

Comment: I think it means "supports all standard features you'd need", in comparison to environments where I/O is more limited. Don't know if there's a precise term for it.

Comment: Indeed, that rosettacode page you found is unrelated, it talks about dynamic variable environments, not about runtimes.

Comment: @CertainPerformance What is a second class runtime environment?

Comment: I don't know if such a term exists. I believe "first-class" is simply meant to distinguish from more limited environments.

Comment: This is a weird [choice of words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/first_class#English) - it's definitely not an established term. Probably the author meant to distinguish it from a browser runtime environment, which is heavily sandboxed (and cannot do any of the things listed in the quote)

Comment: @Bergi I added more context from the book

Comment: The context seems to affirm @Bergi's latest comment.

Comment: Btw, "*JavaScript wasn’t a player in that space*" is not true. JS was designed and implemented as a server-side language from the very beginning. The products did stay in a niche though because they couldn't compete on performance, which only changed with V8.